# Am trying to use spacy with the bert transformer model to classify some values, I however keep getting this error

Tags: python, nlp, spacy, bert-language-model

> The code is in python, using spacy v3, the model is
> (en_core_web_trf)..I suspect it might be the cause, that am using the
> *emphasized text*wrong syntax, but i need to know for sure.
> what the hell else should i add, damn this context stackoverflow

```
import spacy
import torch

nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_trf')

class Category:
    BOOKS = "BOOKS"
    BANK = "BANK"

train_x = ["good characters and plot progression", "check out the book", "good story, would recommend", "novel recommendation", "need to make a deposit to the bank", "balance inquiry savings", "save money"]
train_y = [Category.BOOKS, Category.BOOKS, Category.BOOKS, Category.BOOKS, Category.BANK, Category.BANK, Category.BANK]

from sklearn import svm

docs = [nlp(text) for text in train_x]
train_x_vectors = [doc.vector for doc in docs]
clf_svm = svm.SVC(kernel='linear')

clf_svm.fit(train_x_vectors, train_y)

test_x = ["book"]
docs = [nlp(text) for text in test_x]
test_x_vectors = [doc.vector for doc in docs]

clf_svm.predict(test_x_vectors)
```

> Blockquote

this is the full trace back error message

> Blockquote

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[25], line 7
      4 train_x_vectors = [doc.vector for doc in docs]
      5 clf_svm = svm.SVC(kernel='linear')
----> 7 clf_svm.fit(train_x_vectors, train_y)
      9 test_x = ["book"]
     10 docs = [nlp(text) for text in test_x]

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\sklearn\base.py:1152, in _fit_context.<locals>.decorator.<locals>.wrapper(estimator, *args, **kwargs)
   1145     estimator._validate_params()
   1147 with config_context(
   1148     skip_parameter_validation=(
   1149         prefer_skip_nested_validation or global_skip_validation
   1150     )
   1151 ):
-> 1152     return fit_method(estimator, *args, **kwargs)

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\sklearn\svm\_base.py:190, in BaseLibSVM.fit(self, X, y, sample_weight)
    188     check_consistent_length(X, y)
    189 else:
--> 190     X, y = self._validate_data(
    191         X,
    192         y,
    193         dtype=np.float64,
    194         order="C",
    195         accept_sparse="csr",
    196         accept_large_sparse=False,
    197     )
    199 y = self._validate_targets(y)
    201 sample_weight = np.asarray(
    202     [] if sample_weight is None else sample_weight, dtype=np.float64
    203 )

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\sklearn\base.py:622, in BaseEstimator._validate_data(self, X, y, reset, validate_separately, cast_to_ndarray, **check_params)
    620         y = check_array(y, input_name="y", **check_y_params)
    621     else:
--> 622         X, y = check_X_y(X, y, **check_params)
    623     out = X, y
    625 if not no_val_X and check_params.get("ensure_2d", True):

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py:1146, in check_X_y(X, y, accept_sparse, accept_large_sparse, dtype, order, copy, force_all_finite, ensure_2d, allow_nd, multi_output, ensure_min_samples, ensure_min_features, y_numeric, estimator)
   1141         estimator_name = _check_estimator_name(estimator)
   1142     raise ValueError(
   1143         f"{estimator_name} requires y to be passed, but the target y is None"
   1144     )
-> 1146 X = check_array(
   1147     X,
   1148     accept_sparse=accept_sparse,
   1149     accept_large_sparse=accept_large_sparse,
   1150     dtype=dtype,
   1151     order=order,
   1152     copy=copy,
   1153     force_all_finite=force_all_finite,
   1154     ensure_2d=ensure_2d,
   1155     allow_nd=allow_nd,
   1156     ensure_min_samples=ensure_min_samples,
   1157     ensure_min_features=ensure_min_features,
   1158     estimator=estimator,
   1159     input_name="X",
   1160 )
   1162 y = _check_y(y, multi_output=multi_output, y_numeric=y_numeric, estimator=estimator)
   1164 check_consistent_length(X, y)

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py:976, in check_array(array, accept_sparse, accept_large_sparse, dtype, order, copy, force_all_finite, ensure_2d, allow_nd, ensure_min_samples, ensure_min_features, estimator, input_name)
    974     n_features = array.shape[1]
    975     if n_features < ensure_min_features:
--> 976         raise ValueError(
    977             "Found array with %d feature(s) (shape=%s) while"
    978             " a minimum of %d is required%s."
    979             % (n_features, array.shape, ensure_min_features, context)
    980         )
    982 if copy:
    983     if _is_numpy_namespace(xp):
    984         # only make a copy if `array` and `array_orig` may share memory`

ValueError: Found array with 0 feature(s) (shape=(7, 0)) while a minimum of 1 is required by SVC.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
use below code for your assitance 
import spacy
from sklearn import svm

nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_trf')

class Category:
    BOOKS = "BOOKS"
    BANK = "BANK"

train_x = ["good characters and plot progression", "check out the book", "good story, would recommend", "novel recommendation", "need to make a deposit to the bank", "balance inquiry savings", "save money"]
train_y = [Category.BOOKS, Category.BOOKS, Category.BOOKS, Category.BOOKS, Category.BANK, Category.BANK, Category.BANK]

docs = [nlp(text) for text in train_x]
train_x_vectors = [doc.tensor for doc in docs]  # Use doc.tensor instead of doc.vector
clf_svm = svm.SVC(kernel='linear')

clf_svm.fit(train_x_vectors, train_y)

test_x = ["book"]
docs = [nlp(text) for text in test_x]
test_x_vectors = [doc.tensor for doc in docs]  # Use doc.tensor instead of doc.vector

prediction = clf_svm.predict(test_x_vectors)
print(prediction)
```